# Select Matched Pairs from Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select matched pairs from two tables containing similarly structured data. "Matched Pair" here means two rows that reference each other in the 'match' column.

A single-table matched pair example:

```
TABLE
----
id | matchid
1  |   2
2  |   1
```

ID 1 and 2 are a matched pair because each has a match entry for the other.

Now the real question: what is the best (fastest) way to select the matched pairs that appear in both tables:

```
Table ONE (id, matchid)
Table TWO (id, matchid)
```

Example data:

```
ONE                TWO
----               ----
id  | matchid      id  | matchid
1   |   2          2   |   3
2   |   3          3   |   2
3   |   2
4   |   5
5   |   4
```

The desired result is a single row with IDs 2 and 3.

```
RESULT
----
id  | id
2   | 3
```

This is because 2 & 3 are a matched pair in table ONE and in table TWO. 4 & 5 are a matched pair in table ONE but not TWO, so we don't select them. 1 and 2 are not a match pair at all since 2 does not have a matching entry for 1.

I can get the matched pairs from one table with this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
    FROM ONE a JOIN ONE b
       ON a.id = b.matchid AND a.matchid = b.id
    WHERE a.id < b.id
```

How should I build a query that selects only the matching pairs that appear in both tables?

Should I:

- Select the query above for each table and WHERE EXISTS them together?
- Select the query above for each table and JOIN them together?
- Select the query above then JOIN table TWO twice, once for 'id' and once for 'matchid'?
- Select the query above for each table and loop through to compare them back in php?
- Somehow filter table TWO down so we only have to look at the IDs in matched pairs in table ONE?
- Do something totally different?

(Since this is a question of efficiency, it is worth noting that the matches will be quite sparse, maybe 1/1000 or less, and each table will have 100,000+ rows.)

Comment: Aren't you just trying to JOIN on a.matchid = b.matchid?

Comment: @sashkello - not quite. There has to be two rows in the table, each matching the other. Then those matches have to exist in both tables.

Comment: I don't get your idea. It seem like a simple question which you over-complicated...

Comment: try my answer below `:D`

Comment: Note that the existence of data (like the relation between `id` and `matchid`) in multiple tables might be considered a sign of bad database design, since it is redundant and therefore prone to inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get your point. You want to filter the records in which **the pairs exists on both tables**.

```
SELECT  LEAST(a.ID, a.MatchID) ID, GREATEST(a.ID, a.MatchID) MatchID
FROM    One a
        INNER JOIN Two b
            ON a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.matchID = b.matchID
GROUP   BY LEAST(a.ID, a.MatchID), GREATEST(a.ID, a.MatchID)
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ab00/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
   select 
    O.id,
    O.matchid
    from 
    ONE O
    where 
    (CAST(O.id as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(O.matchid as CHAR(50)))
    in (select CAST(T.id as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(T.matchid as CHAR(50)) from TWO T)
```

**Edited Query:**

```
select distinct
Least(O.id,O.matchid) ID,
Greatest(O.id,O.matchid) MatchID
from 
ONE O
where 
(CAST(O.id as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(O.matchid as CHAR(50)))
in (select CAST(T.id as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(T.matchid as CHAR(50)) from TWO T)
and (CAST(O.matchid as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(O.id as CHAR(50)))
in (select CAST(T.id as CHAR(50))+'~'+CAST(T.matchid as CHAR(50)) from TWO T)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ab00/6)**

Answer (score 0):

Naive version, which checks *all the four rows* that need to exist:

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH both_one AS (
        SELECT o.id, o.matchid
        FROM one o
        WHERE o.id < o.matchid
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM one x WHERE x.id = o.matchid AND x.matchid = o.id)
        )
, both_two AS (
        SELECT t.id, t.matchid
        FROM two t
        WHERE t.id < t.matchid
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM two x WHERE x.id = t.matchid AND x.matchid = t.id)
        )
SELECT *
FROM both_one oo
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM both_two tt
        WHERE tt.id = oo.id AND tt.matchid = oo.matchid
        );
```

This one is simpler :

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH pair AS (
        SELECT o.id, o.matchid
        FROM one o
        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM two x WHERE x.id = o.id AND x.matchid = o.matchid)
        )
SELECT *
FROM pair pp
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM pair xx
        WHERE xx.id = pp.matchid AND xx.matchid = pp.id
        )
AND pp.id < pp.matchid
        ;
```